# Elastic match_bool_prefix and must

Tags: elasticsearch

According to docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-bool-prefix-query.html `match_bool_prefix` is equivalent to

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should": [
        { "term": { "message": "quick" }},
        { "term": { "message": "brown" }},
        { "prefix": { "message": "f"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there an equivalent query that is equivalent to

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must": [
        { "term": { "message": "quick" }},
        { "term": { "message": "brown" }},
        { "prefix": { "message": "f"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit based on comment:**

You can impose an AND condition on the match_bool_prefix query by setting the `operator` parameter as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_bool_prefix": {
      "message": {
        "query": "quick brown f",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this is not exactly equivalent to the bool > must query in your example, because that query requires an exact match (`term` query) of two different values for the same field (`message`, in your case).

[Docs on `term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

Comment: For the string 'quick brown f' I want to find documents that have `quick` term AND `brown` term and a term that starts with `f`. Not OR.

Comment: oh, I see the intention now, I was thinking literally. Let me update my answer

Comment: Are you sure that this query is working as expected?